# Procmail - passing body to bash script

Tags: bash, procmail

I have one liner mails that I wish to send from procmail into a bash script. I only want the body to be sent, nothing else.

Currently my `.procmailrc` looks like this:

```
:0
  *^ Subject.*Xecute Command$
   {
    :0 bf
    | /bin/bash /path/to/script
   }
```

And my Bash script is simple:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "\rLT 4>$0\r\r" > /dev/ttyS1
```

I don't get any input or output from anywhere.

Any pointers?

Comment: I guess you should use $@ instead of $0

Comment: That was quick ... let me do a check quickly ...

Comment: Nope ... it is doing the same ...

Comment: Oh, stupid me... Of course, your program are not receiving anything in the **parameters** ($1, $2 or the whole $@ thing), because mail is piped to it's standard INPUT. So you have to `cat` to /dev/ttyS1

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to add some decorations to the email message and print it to a serial port (?), try a recipe like

```
:0b
*^ Subject.*Xecute Command$
| ( printf '\rLT 4>'; cat -; printf '\r\r' ) > /dev/ttyS1
```

The `b` flag applies to the action line if the condition matches, so you don't need the braces and a new conditionless recipe; [the `f` flag makes no sense at all in this context](http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#lockfile). (Though if you want to keep the message for further processing, you'll want to add a `c` flag.)

Also, for the record, `$0` in Bash is the name of the currently running script (or `bash` itself, if not running a script), and `$@` is the list of command-line arguments. But Procmail doesn't use either of these when it pipes a message to a script; it is simply being made available on standard input.

If you want the action in an external script, that's fine, too, of course; but a simple action like this is probably better written inline. You don't want or need to specify `bash` explicitly if the script file is executable and has a proper shebang; the reason to have a shebang is to make the script self-contained.

In response to comments, here is a simple Perl script to extract the first line of the first body part, and perform substitutions.

```
 perl -nle 'next if 1../^$/;
    s/\<foo\>/bar/g;
    print "\rLT 4>$_\r\r"; exit(0)'
```

This would not be hard to do in `sed` either, provided your `sed` understands `\r`.

Comment: This works perfectly ... however ... ALL the mime information  is sent with the body together with the message ID ... 

 --00a113d242456f2d7052a01e4b6
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
One line message from mail body
--00a113d242456f2d7052a01e4b6

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what "body" means in this context. If you know it's just a single line in the first body part, you can change the action to something like `sed -n -e '1,/^$/d' -e 's/.*/\rLT 4>&\r\r/p' -e q` -- you can also factor in the decorations, provided your `sed` understands `\r`.

Comment: Ok ... allow me to explain what it does ... The message in the body (which is a one line message with max 96 characters) has to be send to a TNC (Tuneable Node Controller) which sits on /dev/ttyS1 ... the first "\r" sends a line break character to "zero" everything inside the TNC command line ... the "LT 4>" tells the TNC that something must be written into the "LT 4" buffer (in this case it is the one line message in the mail body ... the last 2 "\r\r" just clears the input buffer again with line breaks ... Ideally I would like the body to be sent to a bash script to allow further processing

Comment: Like the answer says, you can inline even complex scripts, or use an external script even for trivial processing. Does this now work for you, or do you need further help?

Comment: O.k thank you ... I have made the changes and it works fine ... and it appears to be a sound answer ... however ... is there a way to pipe the body to a BASH script rather ... just to allow me to do some more processing on it like weeding out unwanted words, ensure that the format is acceptable etc ...

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show the complete message. You might be interested in using [`formail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/formail.1.html) to help parse messages.

Comment: Complete message: "AB1CDE A message to demonstrate an example" ... the "AB1CDE" will change every time ... it is a unique code from the originator ... the rest of the message would just be normal text ... hope it helps ...

Comment: Your full stop key appears to be stuck.

Comment: Trust me, it's worse; much worse. See updated answer now.

Comment: I am going to leave it at that. Your updated answer seems to do what I want to do. Thanks all who helped ... Danny

Answer (score 0):

Write your script like that:

```
{
echo -e "\rLT 4>"
cat
echo -e "\r\r"
} > /dev/ttyS1
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion ... but still no reaction from it ... it appears as if "tripleee" is on the right track ... thank you for your effort ...

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried writing the output to some temporary file instead of /dev/ttyS1? The script body does exactly the same as in tripleee's example.

Answer (score 0):

formail is your friend!
Pipe the message into:

```
:0
*^ Subject.*Xecute Command$
| formail -I "" | your-bash-script
```